# URL shortening by replacing GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a web page that displays news content. The URL to the pages looks something like 
`example.com/news.php?newsid=iphone4-releases`. I want the page to be accessible through a URL like this: `example.com/news/iphone4-releases`

I made these changes in my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-l

RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/news.php?newsid=$1 [NC]
```

This code actually replaces the URL, but I want to preserve the same URL without the GET variables. Also, using this method the URL becomes `example.com/iphone4-releases` but I want `example.com/news/iphone4-releases`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do, assuming you will only use a-Z, digits and a dash in your article name:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)$ /news.php?newsid=$1 [NC]
```

**Edit:**

This link explains about the parameters:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

And about the -l:

> '-l' (is symbolic link) Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests
>   whether or not it exists, and is a symbolic link.

And numbers will work in this example (eg. /news/iphone2003-new-launch)

Im sorry, but im a hurry :)

Comment: I use numbers too in my newsid. Can you please explain why you removed !-l from rewrite condition (and what it does)

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect to omit GET variables and use .htaccess to do a 303 redirect because the redirect will lose your variables.  What you can do is submit a form with POST to the page you will be redirecting to and create a symlink from that page to the real PHP script, and *then* create a rewrite rule to redirect the client's browser.

Here's your above redirect, incorporating the added `/news/` section:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-l

RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ news/news.php?newsid=$1 [NC]
```

You can also do a redirect using only PHP:

```
header("Location: http://www.redirecthere.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will need to remove both `[OR]` because you want the requested file not to be file AND not to be directory AND not to be a symbolic link

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-l

RewriteRule ^/(\w+)/(.*?)/?$      $1.php?newsid=$2 [NC,L]
```

and you don't need the whole domain to be inside your rule